# WPF XAML Windows 11 Accent Color

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Is there a simple way to get the `Windows 10` / `Windows 11` accent color in `XAML`?

I looked at many examples, but most of them do not work. I also saw some examples that mimic the color changing behavior in `C#`, but they do not work in `Windows 11`.

My code:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}"
    Color="{x:Static SystemParameters.WindowGlassBrush}"/>
```

I just want to set the `Color` to windows current accent color.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What worked in `Windows 10`, works also in `Windows 11`.

OS: `Windows 11 Build 10.0.22000.282`

VS: `2022 Preview 7.0`

WPF: `.NET 6`

```
UserLabel.Background = SystemParameters.WindowGlassBrush;
```

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}" BasedOn="{StaticResource TextBase}"
       x:Key="TextColored">
    <Setter Property="FontWeight"
            Value="SemiBold"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground"
            Value="{x:Static SystemParameters.WindowGlassBrush}"/>
</Style>
```

This worked without adding any `NuGets`.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to retrieve the accent colour using the `UISettings.GetColorValue` WinRT API.

Depending on whether you target .NET 5 or an earlier version, you should either set the `TargetFramework` to *net5.0-windows10.0.** or install the `Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contracts` NuGet package as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/desktop-to-uwp-enhance?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077).

You can then create a `SolidColorBrush` using the return value of the API:

```
var color = new Windows.UI.ViewManagement.UISettings()
    .GetColorValue(UIColorType.Accent);
var brush = new SolidColorBrush
    (Color.FromArgb(color.A, color.R, color.G, color.B));
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I added the `NuGet` package and edited the `Target Framework`, but VS did not recognize `Windows.UI`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm using `.NET 6` and all Windows 11 features are working perfectly. I tried `net6.0-windows10.0.19041.0` and `net5.0-windows10.0.19041.0`  as the `Target Framework`, but building failed in both tries.